# Is it possible to view entries in admin panel list view with specific field?

Tags: entry

I want to add a checkbox field to all my entries.

But the key factor being that if 3 entries from 100 have this checkbox enabled, the 3 entries will show in the list of 100+ entries with a specific colour/sign/ anything really that makes it stand out and shows that this entry has this field checked.

Im hoping I made sense!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the cog at the bottom of the panel to choose which columns to show in the entries table

[image: Cog to change which columns are shown]

This then highlights which entries have the checkbox enabled:

[image: Shows which entries have the the checbox selected]

Unfortunately, I don't think you can sort on this sort of column with core.

Some plugins may help here, if you want more control, e.g.

https://github.com/mmikkel/CpSortableCustomColumns-Craft

Or for a lot more options/control in this area:

https://zenbustudio.com/software/zenbu-craftcms

Comment: The only issue is that the CpSortable plugin doesnt sort by checkbox, its not an available field type ;[

Comment: Hmm, I thought it could, but I uninstalled it since it breaks with Commerce a bit.  Shame.  Maybe trial Zenbu?  At least you can see them easily now...